# How to make a Javascript form validation with coloured textbox (red/green) without using inline css?

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

So I have made a Javascript form validation where I get an alert message if nothing is written in the form. Instead of an alert message I want a coloured (red/green) textbox. When you don't write anything in it and try to submit it, you get a red box with a message. When you write down what you need to write and submit it, you get a green box.

```
function validateFormC() {
  let x = document.forms["contactForm"]["name_contact"].value;
  if (x === "") {
   alert("Don't forget to write down your name!");
  return false;
  }
```

I already know how to make coloured checkboxes with html. I need to know how to do it with Javascript for a school project. But it's important that I don't use inline css. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use classes for styling.

Comment: You can simply set up CSS classes and change your input classes using `inputElement.classlist`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class selector in CSS:

```
.red-input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

then in your JavaScript you can select the element and add that class to it:

```
// With Vanilla JavaScript
document.getElementById('input_id').classList.add('red-input');

// With jQuery
$('#input_id').addClass('red-input')
```

Comment: Okay thanks I get that. But what do I need to change in my function above now?

I tried some things but it doesn't really work. Can't seem to figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

You need something along the lines of:

```
var warnMessage = document.createElement("div");
    warnMessage.innerHTML = "Don't forget to write down your name!";
    warnMessage.setAttribute('class', 'warnMessage');
    document.body.appendChild(warnMessage);
```

Then create a matching CSS style : `warnMessage`  probably with `bgcolor:red;`
Same again for your success message, but green.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You can change borderColor to backgroundColor if you prefer.

```
function validateFormC() {
  var x = document.forms["contactForm"]["name_contact"];
  if (x.value === "") {
    alert("Don't forget to write down your name!");
    x.style.borderColor = 'red';
    return false;
  }
  else
    x.style.borderColor = 'green';
}
```